# is this mathematical assumption about count the leading zero right?

Tags: c++, math

there are 4 unsigned integers(32bits):

`a,b,c,d (c > a > d > b)`

and a function:

`clz(x)` (calculate the leading zero numbers of x.eg.`clz(2) == 30`)

then there are :

`n = clz(a^b) // xor
 m = clz(c^d)`

the question is: can we think m is certainly lesser or equal then n?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried convincing yourself by writing it down on paper?

Comment: Counting the leading zeros in the binary representation of an unsigned integer?

Comment: What does this have to do with C++?

Answer (score 2):

consider a simplified version: c=0x0111, a=0x0110, d=0x0101, b=0x0001

then c^d=0x0010, a^b=0x0111, so clz(c^d)=2 > clz(a^b)=1

So all you need is a,c,d having the same lz and b having a larger lz to fail the assumption.